# move from old hosting company to AWS

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, migration

I have a website www.website.com, it is hosted with company A, I have built a new site on AWS with a temporary URL www.tempurl.com

I want to make it so www.website.com points at the new site. I want to keep emails hosted with company A. Do I just give company A the IP address of the new site and ask them to point the A Record? Or does anything need setting up on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can reach the site over the internet using `www.tempurl.com` and that emails are currently working, then you should be able to just update the DNS A record for the production host to point to the new IP address and DON'T change the existing MX records.

You also want to keep in mind the fact that if you do not use elastic IP on AWS, then your public IP address for the AWS server will change if it is restarted.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html for more details.